# How to stop from losing my singing ability

Tags: voice

I am writing this here to get some solutions on my problem where I am not able to sing now. Actually, I have moved from my hometown in the North to Bangalore around 5 months back (for job) and since then my voice has gotten worse. I not bragging but just to support my above statement, I used to sing very melodiously.
It could be that the water, food and/or air didn't suit me here. I don't want to loose my voice. I play guitar, make electronic music also and I have invested so much of my time and efforts into this field. And the most importantly, God has blessed me with such a beautiful voice, I don't want to let it go just like that. I have started sounding awful in singing and when I push myself to sing more properly/harder, it puts a load on my throat, chest and all. I am not even able to have the air volume as I used to have before shifting to this new city.

Singing, playing guitar and making music is the only thing which helps me get rid of stress. Doesn't matter what I am suffering from, I just feel relaxed and stressless after going into this zone. Singing and music is the only this which makes me happy.

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about medical advice, something that is out of scope for this site.

Comment: I once discovered I would lose my voice if the place was air-conditioned. This was no kind of scientific study, just one place, every time they closed it in at night & put the air-con on, my voice would go within half an hour. I sang in different places in the same town every night for two weeks. None of the others, including ones that were constantly air-conditioned did this, but that one place who power up the AC hard after closing all the big scenic doors for the night, it happened on the two occasions I was there.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good site for obtaining medical advice! Please visit a Phoniatrician, who will be able to diagnose the cause of your problems (which also includes looking at what you prefer to eat, as this can cause vocal problems) and might suggest a treatment plan to make it better. If you do have persisting vocal problem and you do not treat them properly there will be a risk for irreversible damages to your voice or damages that would require surgery to treat!

At the very best we could give you suggestions about specific topics (i.e. how to sing without straining the voice, or something), but we can neither accurately tell you what is wrong with your voice, nor can we tell you what to do to make it better.

Comment: What the heck is a phoniatrician? / I was going to say, go see an ear nose and throat specialist (otorhinolaringólogo in Spanish -- not sure what it's called where you live.  In the meantime, while you're waiting for your appointment, work on your music theory, conducting, instrument, etc., attend concerts and interesting rehearsals (with permission), and be patient.

Comment: A phoniatrician (or voice doctor) is a specialist for problems concerning speech and voice. Here in Austria this is an extra qualification for an ear-nose-throat doctor.

Comment: I wonder if there is such a thing in the US.